# Cypress won't open the specified URL

Tags: javascript, cypress

When I run the test, the specified URL does not open, even though it is entered correctly and set in BaseUrl in cypress.config.js:

```
> module.exports = defineConfig({   e2e: {
>     "projectId": "fi4fhz",
>     "viewportHeight": 1080,
>     "viewportWidth": 1920,
>     specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
>     baseUrl: 'https://pha.mm.int:6001/',
>    
>        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
> 
>     },   },
```

[image]

---

In every test file I have this:

```js
 beforeEach(() => {
        cy.runInWeb();
    });
```

and in commands.js I have:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("runInWeb", () => { cy.visit(Cypress.e2e().projectUrl) });
```

and in cypress.config.js I have:

```js
"projectUrl": "https://pha.mm.int:6001/"
```

but it's not functioning. Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you include the code where this is failing?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you visit() but not in the right way, if you store your url in env variable you get it out like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("runInWeb", () => { cy.visit(Cypress.env('projectUrl')) });
```

and you store the default like this:

```js
// cypress.config.js

const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'
  },
  env: {
    projectUrl: 'https://pha.mm.int:6001/',
  },
})
```

or `cypress.env.json`

```js
{
  "projectUrl": "https://pha.mm.int:6001/"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The baseUrl value `https://pha.mm.int:6001/` shows up in the browser address bar because Cypress uses it to configure set up the runner.

But the `<iframe>` containing the web page under test isn't changed until you perform
the first `cy.visit('/')`.

This is to allow you to execute code before the page load occurs, like `cy.intercept()` and `cy.fixture()`.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have this beforeEach prior to running your it test blocks. You need to use `cy.visit('/')` before each of your tests.

```
beforeEach(() => {  
        //cy.session(id, setup); Use is if you want to stay logged into your application
        cy.visit('/);
        cy.wait(100);
      });
```

If you're interested in using a session, [visit the cypress docs here:](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/sessionhttps://)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information in the question, I assume that you did not include [a `cy.visit()` command.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit) Without that command, Cypress does not know to open a webpage.